# Implementing auto-renewable subscription with promotional offer

Tags: codenameone

We have a working auto-renewable subscription that gives a free trial using [introductory offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_introductory_offers_in_your_app) for apple, but there are eligibility rules with this type of offer that doesn't satisfy what we need. [Promotional offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/setting_up_promotional_offers) in the App Store is a solution that does though.

The Codename One [Purchase API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/payment/Purchase.html), seems to not handle the generated keys from the promotional offer. What is the solution to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't that something that you handle on the server side of the payment? I'll check with Steve as I didn't really touch subscriptions.

Comment: Yeah there are keys generated from Apple's side in order to create promotional offers in the first place and was just wondering if there was currently a codename one way to handle it simply! Thank you

Comment: It seems that we need to make some changes to IAP to support this. I suggest filing an RFE for this and I'll assign it to Steve to keep track.

Comment: Filed it here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3696
Looking forward for the implementation! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is now [committed to git](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/93b0419a2b1d31bd64a1e455ece2ffa63bab7837) and should be a part of version 7.0.105 arriving next Friday.