# Generating a Signature for Apple Promotional Offers

Tags: codenameone

This is a follow up on a question I had [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76007543/implementing-auto-renewable-subscription-with-promotional-offer) and thank you to Codename One for implementing promotional offers!

I am having trouble generating the signature. The following snippet of code is what I have to generate the signature, but it is giving a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: initialisation vector must be the same length as block size` error

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.decode(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);


Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
ecdsaSign.initSign(keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec));
ecdsaSign.update(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The `key` variable is a string that contains the downloaded PKCS #8 private key from App Store Connect without the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----" parts/

And the `stringToSign` contains a combined string of what is listed on [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/generating_a_signature_for_promotional_offers?language=objc) for promotional offers.

```
String stringToEncrypt = "appBundleId" + "\u2063"
                                + applePromotionalOffer.getKeyIdentifier() + "\u2063"
                                + "productIdentifier" + "\u2063"
                                + applePromotionalOffer.getOfferIdentifier() + "\u2063"
                                + "" + "\u2063"
                                + applePromotionalOffer.getNonce() + "\u2063" + applePromotionalOffer.getTimestamp();
```

There may be problems with my combined string as well

```
ApplePromotionalOffer applePromotionalOffer = new ApplePromotionalOffer();
applePromotionalOffer.setOfferIdentifier("offerIdentifier");
applePromotionalOffer.setNonce(getGUID().toLowerCase()); // getGUID is a method we have made
applePromotionalOffer.setKeyIdentifier("keyIdentifier");
applePromotionalOffer.setTimestamp(getCurrentEpochInGMTTime()); // getCurrentEpochInGMTTime is a method we have made
```

Comment: This is server side code, right?
Check the length of `encoded` in the debugger and verify that it matches the exact fixed length. If not you need to check Apples documentation to understand how this can be adapted.

Comment: I made an error calling another encryption method rather than calling the following snippet of code I gave. Sorry for the confusion!


This is not server side code and I'm now realizing that making the proper method call I am using Java libraries that will not work with Codename One such as the KeyFactory, PKCS8EncodedKeySpec, and the Signature.


The promotional offers needs the combined string `stringToSign` to be ECDSA with SHA256 signed. Am I over looking or missing something with trying to use the new promotional offer update? Is the Bouncy Castle library able to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure since we didn't implement the promotional offers before. Why can't this be done in your server side? Why does the code need to execute in the device?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It's just what I did, but nothing happens by passing the applePromotionalOffer object along with an appropriate SKU into the subscribe(String sku, PromotionalOffer promotionalOffer) method in the new Purchase API.

I am testing through TestFlight and I'm also wondering of a way to see a log, so I can figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: Install the native logging cn1lib using Codename One Settings. It will provide access to the device native logs so you can track what's printed more easily.

Comment: Thank you again for another good suggestion! I am given a `Found nil parameter when creating SKPaymentDiscount` after calling the method subscribe(String sku, PromotionalOffer promotionalOffer). It seem to be a common [problem](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/1123)... not sure where I go from here

Comment: Just for more context as well... the offerIdentifier set is URL-encoded and the OS version of my test device is iOS 16

Comment: Looking at [this code](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/93b0419a2b1d31bd64a1e455ece2ffa63bab7837/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/IOSNative.m#L6198), it seems that Steve checked all the arguments for nil and the right type before extracting them so this is weird. I'll check if he has an idea.

Comment: The only place I can see a nil value seeping through is on the nonce, if you provide an invalid UUID.  What does the nonce string look like that you are providing?

Comment: Okay I thought the nonce could just be any random string as long as its lower case, so I had been passing a randomly generated string associated to a user. For this case, I had it setup as "lxzyadw2u5it5vhfkbx20yjrri53f5kr" which isn't a valid UUID. I will do another test and hopefully get it to work! Will let you know

Comment: I am now getting an "Unable to Purchase" response from the store. Here are the parameter values of the combined string I am signing (using "|" to space out the values for readability here):

`App Bundle ID: com.codename1.myapp` | 
`Key Identifier: M3BC5QFF3W (changed up characters from the actual key)` | 
`Product Identifier: year_10off_then_renew_to_base_price` | 
`Offer Identifier: 10%25%20Off%20First%20Year%20then%20Renews%20to%20Original (encoded the spaces and %)`  | 
`App Account Token: Empty or email of user` | 
`Nonce: 29b4164d-6fbb-a438-a20c-8c9239b11cc3 (randomized each time)`

Comment: The product identifier in the combined string is the productID of the promotional offer itself. However, I am passing the SKU of the parent productID from the App Store Connect for the method `subscribe(String sku, PromotionalOffer promotionalOffer)`; otherwise, nothing happens at all and all the feedback I get is from the native logs.

Comment: Apologies for the lengthy comments, but after responding with the only "ok" button for the "Unable to Purchase" response. I can get logs by trying again in which it gives a `Transaction error - Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=11 "(null)"` and an `Error Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3900 " Unable to Purchase"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the promotional offer to show and writing an answer for future developers trying to use the implemented support by Codename One for promotional offers on iOS:

When creating the combined string of `appBundleId + '\u2063' + keyIdentifier + '\u2063' + productIdentifier + '\u2063' + offerIdentifier + '\u2063' + appAccountToken + '\u2063' + nonce + '\u2063' + timestamp`, it's best to avoid spacing and special characters for both the productIdentifier and offerIdentifier.

And the **offerIdentifier** in this combined string should be what is associated to the promotional offer itself, but the productIdentifier(SKU) that you pass into the subscribe(String sku, PromotionalOffer promotionalOffer) should be the "parent" or "base" productIdentifier that the promotional offer is attached to. The same goes with the **productIdentifier** that goes in the combined string

Thank you [Shai Almog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756809/shai-almog), [Steve Hannah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2935174/steve-hannah), and the rest of the Codename One team for the hard work!