# Promotional Offer Errors

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, codenameone

Able to show the promotional offer thanks to support [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159273/generating-a-signature-for-apple-promotional-offers?noredirect=1#comment134359266_76159273), but after going through the payment process, inputting my password, and confirming the purchase, I get an **error popup that says "Unable to Purchase. Contact the developer for more information."**

In the logs, I get the following errors:

- **SKErrorDomain Code=12 "(null)"**
- **ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3903 "Unable to Purchase"**

---

Here are the example parameter values I am passing to the combined string **appBundleId + '\u2063' + keyIdentifier + '\u2063' + productIdentifier + '\u2063' + offerIdentifier + '\u2063' + appAccountToken + '\u2063' + nonce + '\u2063' + timestamp**

- **appBundleId**: com.app.myapp
- **keyIdentifier**: copied the key ID from the App Store Connect
- **productIdentifier**: product_identifier
- **offerIdentifier**: offer_identifier
- **appAccountToken**: tried both a UUID and an empty string
- **nonce**: a UUID to lowercase
- **timestamp**: UNIX timestamp

---

How I'm generating the signature (Java)

```
/* promotionalOfferKey = value between "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----" from the downloaded p8 file from App Store Connect associated with the keyIdentifier parameter above */

// stringToSign = the combined string above

byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(promotionalOfferKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);

Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
ecdsaSign.initSign(keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec));

ecdsaSign.update(stringToSign.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();

signatureToReturn = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
```

---

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure. I'll check with Steve

Comment: Searching for resources, it seems that error code 12 could be due to an invalid signature. There is the "null" included in the error though, which I'm not sure why because I am setting it using the `setSignature(signatureResult)` Codename One implemented when the API returns **signatureToReturn** from the code above. Perhaps its an actual error with the signature generation itself or something in the **new purchase method** with the apple promotional offer object parameter? Please advise on how the CN1 team got it to work

Comment: @ShaiAlmog We finally got the "Successful Purchase" popup with promotional offers on TestFlight with the "Okay" button prompt, but now the problem is that it just literally crashes our app? Reporting the crash does not provide any logs on Xcode. Please advise! Almost there

Comment: You have this running on xcode? Do you see anything printed in the logs? Also can you update on how you solved the previous problem so future developers can learn from that?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog No I am testing on a real device through TestFlight and there are no logs even though I report the crashes that happen when the "Successful Purchase" pops up. I just updated the [answer I had before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159273/generating-a-signature-for-apple-promotional-offers?noredirect=1#comment134359266_76159273) as we found that error 12 was due to an invalid signature and it made sense to answer in that post!

Comment: @ShaiAlmog got promotional offers to fully work now. The app was crashing after a successful purchase, because I was not on a sandbox account. Thank you and Steve for all the support!

Comment: Great to hear! FYI for future reference you can inspect device logs directly in xcode under the organizer.